# After downloading zip folder the code next to it is not working

Tags: codeigniter

I am working with PHP code igniter i wrote below code to download the file.
Which reads file and download it as zip. It working fine. But when i write other code below download it stop working. For example if i echo the sum two digit it wont work. Will any one guide me on this.

```
$this->zip->read_file($path);
$filename= "zip-name";
$done = $this->zip->download($filename);
```

//Below code not working

```
$a=10;
$b=10;
echo $a+$b;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's intended behaviour. See the hint in Codeigniter Docs for that function:

```
Do not display any data in the controller in which you call this method since it sends various server headers that cause the download to happen and the file to be treated as binary.
```

That's why download platforms typically do a delayed, JavaScript controlled redirect ("Your Download will start shortly..")